# Sequelize Typescript find() method

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am using typescript + nodejs and for database postgres.

I have a model named Note given below.

```
import sequelize from "../connect";
import {
  DataTypes,
  Model,
  InferAttributes,
  InferCreationAttributes,
  CreationOptional,
} from "sequelize";

interface NoteModel
  extends Model<
    InferAttributes<NoteModel>,
    InferCreationAttributes<NoteModel>
  > {
  id: number;
  title: CreationOptional<string>;
  content: string;
  age: CreationOptional<number>;
}

// And with a functional approach defining a module looks like this
const Note = sequelize.define<NoteModel>(
  "Note",
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(64),
      defaultValue: "Unnamed Note",
    },
    content: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(4096),
      allowNull: false,
    },
    age: {
      type: new DataTypes.INTEGER(),
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
  {
    tableName: "notes",`
  }
);
export default Note;
```

When I am using

```
await Note.create({title: "My First Note", content: "My First Note Content"}); // no warnings
```

When I do

```
await Note.create({title: "My First Note", content: 5}); // I get a warning content is of type string
```

My question is when I am doing a find I don't get any warnings for type mismatch

```
await Note.findOne({ where: { content: 5 } });  // type of content should be string, even if I provide number. typescript does not yell at me.
```

I have tried following the official documentation of sequelize but have not seen any solution for my problem.

Comment: The content property in the Note model is of type string, but the value you are providing is of type number.  You can explicitly specify the type of the content property in the where object.                                                                                                                                 
 await Note.findOne({
  where: {
    content: {
      type: String,
      value: 5,
    },
  },
});

Comment: Thanks @shubhkr1 for the answer, even after doing

Note.findOne({ where: { content: { type: String, value: 5, }, }, }); It does not give any type warnings as to why number is used instead of string.